# Excel If Function for Multiple If's

Tags: excel

For the below, I'm looking for an excel if function that'll let me know how old each of the items are (less than 3 days, Less than 7 days, Less than 14 days, Greater than 14 days)

[image: excel worksheet]

Comment: Use a formula similar to `=B2-Today()` to give you the number of days ago for your "Aging" cell. Then you could use Conditional Formatting to change the color of that cell based on the range of days aged.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table outlining your cut offs and then use a `VLOOKUP`.

In C2, add `=VLOOKUP(TODAY()-B2,$F$2:$G$6,2,1)` and drag down as needed

---

[image]

---

*The benefit with going this route is that you don't have to update complicated `IF` statements if you ever needed to change the buckets. Say for instance, in the future you want to add 5 more categories. Here that would just mean updating 5 rows on a single table rather nesting 5 more criteria to an `IF` statement.*

Comment: I added in a negative value since I wasn't sure if you would ever have future dates. I assumed all dates were in 2020 which makes your DVD date future dated.

Comment: You can even embed a lookup table into the formula, it will also be easier than infinite ```if``` conditions: ```=VLOOKUP(TODAY()-B2,{-100000;"Future dated",1;"Less than 3",4;"Less than 7",8;"Less than 14",15;"Greater than 14"},2,1)```

Answer (score 0):

A simple verbose formula...

```
=IF(TODAY()-B3<=7,"Less than equal to seven",IF(TODAY()-B3<=14,"Less than or 
equal to fourteen days",IF(TODAY()-B3<=21,"Less than or equal to twenty one 
days","greater than 21 days")))
```

Need to format the cell this is in as a number with no decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=IF((TODAY()-B1)<3,"Less than 3 days",
IF((TODAY()-B1)<7,"Less than 7 days",
IF((TODAY()-B1)<14,"Less than 14 days",
IF((TODAY()-B1)>=14,"Greater than 14 days",""))))
```

Please notice that I used `>=14`.
Reason is otherwise you wont get the rows where the difference is exactly 14.
But feel free to change it to `>14` if that's fit your need better :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use tha `TODAY()` function to get the current date and than compare it with the dates you have:
[image: spreadsheet example]

so the table that you will have is like:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>5/12/2020</th>
    <th>=TODAY()-B1</th>
    <th>=if(C1<3, "less than 3 days", if(C1<7, "less than 7 days", if(C1<14, "less than 14 days", "more than 14 days")))
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>5/10/2020</th>
    <th>=TODAY()-B2</th>
    <th>=if(C1<3, "less than 3 days", if(C1<7, "less than 7 days", if(C1<14, "less than 14 days", "more than 14 days")))
    </th>
  </tr>
  

</table>
```